# unique constraint violation, when re-ordering values for a property

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to rearrange the order that answers are asked for a given question, by using the `ordinal` property. Because the `ordinal` property has a constraint of being `unique`, for a question instance, I have to assign completely new numbers to avoid a `unique constraint violation`.

For example, if a question has 4 answers and the answers have ordinals of 1,2,3,4, I could not update the ordinals to 3,2,1,4. I would have to update them 7,6,5,8, to change the order. Is there a way to swap values in the `ordinal` field without violating the unique constraint?

### form

[image: form image]

### answer domain

```
class Answer {

    DateTime dateCreated
    DateTime lastUpdated

    String body
    Integer ordinal
    String reason

    static belongsTo = [question: Question]

    static constraints = {
        body blank: false
        ordinal unique: 'question'
    }

    static mapping = {
        question lazy: true
    }

    String toString() {
        "Answer: $body"
    }

    Integer getNextOrdinal() {
        Integer ordinal = Answer.createCriteria().get {
            projections {
                max "ordinal"
            }
        }
        ordinal = ordinal ?: 1
        return ordinal
    }
}
```

### question update controller

```
def update(Long id, Long version) {

    def questionInstance = Question.get(id)

    questionInstance.properties = params

    def ordinals = params.list('ordinals')

    questionInstance.answers.eachWithIndex{ Answer answer, int i ->
        answer.ordinal = ordinals[i].toInteger()
    }        

    if (!questionInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [questionInstance: questionInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = "Question: '${questionInstance.body}' has been updated"
    flash.messageType = "success"
    redirect(action: "index", id: questionInstance.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to understand this error you need to think about what's happening. When you save and flush your instance Hibernate is issuing a series of updates. During the course of these updates it's highly possible (as you have seen) that an updated ordinal value will conflict with an existing one that has yet to be updated during the flush.

In order to avoid this, you need to empty the collection of answers, then attach the updated instances.

So instead of what you currently have:

```
def ordinals = params.list('ordinals')

questionInstance.answers.eachWithIndex{ Answer answer, int i ->
    answer.ordinal = ordinals[i].toInteger()
}
```

You need something more along the lines of:

```
def ordinals = params.list('ordinals')
def answers = []

// collect the existing answers, and update their ordinals
questionInstance.answers.eachWithIndex{ Answer answer, int i ->
  answer.ordinal = ordinals[i].toInteger()
  answers << answer
}

// clear the collection
questionInstance.answers.clear()

// add them back in again with the updated information
answers.each { questionInstance.addToAnswers(it) }
```

That's off the top of my head, so use it as an example of the direction you should head.

P.S. Good luck there at the university!

Comment: thanks, that seemed to fix one problem. I now get another error http://pastebin.com/Jne9CBf7. I'll most likely have to post another question for this